# fpdf multicell not showing values

Tags: php, fpdf

I am creating a pdf which is working but the values are not being entered into the multicell of the pdf.

Lets take the date for example, the user enters a date and on the PDF it should look like:

```
Date: 26/01/2017
```

but this is what it looks like now:

```
Date:
```

Below is my code with the date example:

```
<?php
//set the question values
$questions     = array(
'name' => "Name: ",
'date' => "Date: ",
'first' => "First Day of Leave: ",
'last' => "Last Day of Leave: ",
'days' => "Number of Days Taken: ",
'email' => "Managers Email: ",
'creditdays' => "Leave Days in Credit",
'personnel' => "THIS SECTION TO BE COMPLETED BY PERSONNEL DEPARTMENT",
'credit' => "Leave Days in Credit:",
'mansign' => "Signed:",
'date2' => "Date:",
'authorise' => "Authorised By:",
'date3' => "Date:",
'auth' => "Authorisation Of Leave"
);
//set the question answers
$date          = $_POST['date'];
$first         = $_POST['first'];
$last          = $_POST['last'];
$days          = $_POST['days'];
$email         = $_POST['email'];
$name          = $_POST['name'];
//set the question names
$questionName  = $questions['name'];
$questionDate  = $questions['date'];
$questionFirst = $questions['first'];
$questionLast  = $questions['last'];
$questionDays  = $questions['days'];
$questionEmail = $questions['email'];
$personnel = $questions['personnel'];
$credit = $questions['credit'];
$mansign = $questions['mansign'];
$date2 = $questions['date2'];
$authorise = $questions['authorise'];
$date3 = $questions['date3'];
$auth = $questions['auth'];
//Create the PDF

require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
//insert fields
$pdf->SetDrawColor(100, 100, 100);
$pdf->SetFillColor(100,100,100);  
$pdf->Multicell(200, 3, "Leave Application Form", "", 'C');
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(190, 10, $questionDate, $date, 'C');
```

Comment: $questionDate . $date (not comma) [see my answer for better understanding]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [fpdf manual](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm):

```
MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align [, boolean fill]]])
```

While in your code:

`$pdf->MultiCell(190, 10, $questionDate, $date, 'C')`;

So `$date` isn't part of the **txt parameter** to appear in the cell.
Instead, you need to append the $date variable to the $questionDate one.

`$pdf->MultiCell(190, 10, $questionDate . $date, 'C')`;

Comment: that worked! But now my alignment 'C' isnt working its back to left align?

Comment: Because you first need to pass a value of the "border" parameter and only after that to the "align" parameter.

Comment: If my answer helped you please upvote,approve it. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect! You are the master sir! Thank you I will remember that. I marked your answer as correct and voted it up ( I don't have enough reputation so it doesn't show but just to let you know sir)